# Google Analytics Event Tracking Works But Doesn't Count As Goal Conversion

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking

I'm using Google Analytics for tracking on my website. I'm having a bit of trouble with event tracking, I can see in the realtime tab that the event tracking is working:

```
Event Category  Event Action    Events (Last 30 min)
```

1.  email           signup                 12               100.00%

But for my goal conversion with category=email,action=signup shows 0 goal conversions. Obviously Google Analytics can see the events happening but somehow they're not registering as goals. Has anybody else had this problem before?

Comment: I had such a problem when I accidentally included a whitespace character in my goal definition (GA does not automatically trim leading whitespace). Plus sometimes realtime conversions do not show in the "active users" tab but do appear in the "Goal hit (last 30 minutes)) tab, so you might want to check there. All in all you don't give us much to go on - how does your event tracking code look ? Can you include a screenshot of you goal setup ? And looking at the answer below, goal value is optional and certainly not related to your problem.

Comment: I agree with @EikePierstorff, we need to see your goal configuration, as well as the code you use to track the event.

Answer (score 1):

It takes 24 hours for Google to create non-real-time statistics.

Comment: Have you assigned a value to the goal conversion?

Comment: No I haven't, I thought that was optional? I tried to set goal conversion values to 0, but then they just defaulted back to 'Yes' as in use the sent value. I am not sending a goal conversion value though.

Comment: If you don't set a goal value, then GA will use the value passed in from your event. Are you passing a value from your event?

Comment: I'm not I'll try setting the conversion value and seeing what happens

Comment: Let me know if this works, and I'll update my answer to reflect the correct solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75887/discussion-between-kevintechie-and-user1023465).